# Give a poor person "all that he lacks"?

Tags: tzedakah-charity

The Torah says that we must give a poor person all that he lacks [דֵּ֚י מַחְסֹר֔וֹ אֲשֶׁ֥ר יֶחְסַ֖ר לֽוֹ.] [Deut. 15:7-8]

The Shulḥan Arukh interprets:

> How much should be given to the poor? *Dei machsoro asher yechsar lo* ... All that he lacks... How is that? ... Even if he was used to riding on a horse with a servant running ahead of him while he was rich, and now he is poor, buy him the horse and the servant -- each man according to his needs... If he came to get married, rent a house for him, prepare a bed for him and house utensils, and find him a wife. [Shulḥan Arukh, Yoreh Deah, 250:1]

I would like some sources that elaborate on that.  What if he is a king in exile:  Are you supposed to support him in regal style?  What if you yourself lack what he is accustomed to?  I know that Hillel did that [Ketubot 67b] and that he might die if you don't [Ketubot 67b].  Are there recent cases where this was done?

Comment: Are you talking about places that have enough for all poor people? (I've never heard of such a place.)

Comment: To support DoubleAA's claim -- the Gemara says this is assuming you have enough for everyone's basic needs first ...

Comment: That is certain, but does not answer my questions.

Comment: Also, can you give me that Gemara source you mentioned?